# How can you rename excel header column name when exporting data?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How can you rename & add new columns beside the item attributes when exporting data via ImpEx?

I have the following:

```
"#% impex.setTargetFile( ""attributes.csv"" , true );"
insert_update ClassificationAttribute; pk[unique=true]; code ; creationtime; classes
```

But I want to have, besides code & creationTime, the **name** and the **code** of the classes and subcategories/supercategories of them. For now I can only get the PK.

And I want the columns to be renamed, for example: the `code` column to be renamed into `attribute_code`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to read more at

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/8bef9530866910148e6cff59d9afa127.html

and

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/1c8f5bebdc6e434782ff0cfdb0ca1847.html

and

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/8bd9d5bb86691014ba9d95a88ede75f3.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this using impexes, unless you are okay with having two csvs, one corresponding to classificationattribute and another one for classsification class:

```
"#% impex.setTargetFile( ""ClassificationAttribute.csv"" , true );"
insert_update ClassificationAttribute; pk[unique=true]; code ; creationtime;classes(&Item)

"#% impex.setTargetFile( ""ClassificationClass.csv"" , true );"
insert_update ClassificationClass;&Item;code;name;supercategories(code)
```

The supercategories is a list and classes is also a list, a list of list scenario is not supported in a single line of impex. Even with this in place you cannot reimport the data with a renamed attribute.

You can however, achieve the same using a customized version of excel export and import, OOTB code is implemented using apache POI. Extend `DefaultExcelExportService` and  override create custom export classification attribute. Write the reverse logic after extending `DefaultExcelImportService`, if reimport is required:

```
public class CustomClassificationExportServiceImpl extends DefaultExcelExportService implements CustomExportService{

public class CustomClassificationImportServiceImpl extends DefaultExcelImportService implements CustomImportService{
```

1. Create custom method for classification export. This method fetches the classes corresponding to each classificationattribute as a list and converts this into a set of excel cells.
2. Create a meta excel sheet that stores the mapping of the actual attribute with the alias attribute given (if reimport required).
3. Implement the custom logic for import in DefaultExcelImportService. This should fetch the actual attribute using metadata, convert the excel columns to a list etc